# Conflict of the assembly System.Runtime.Serialization between versions and publicyKeyTokens

Tags: .net, assembly-binding-redirect

I have an old project that I opened on Visual Studio 2017.
It starts to warning about a conflict in the assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.

The problem here is that the assembly versions have both the same name but different publicyKeyToken.

> No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes". Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

I tried put some runtime redirect combinations in my web.config but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Same problem. In my case, I'm using Xamarin in VS 2017 and this happen only when I ran the application in a Android emulator. So, I need use my phisical device :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem in several projects when compiling using VS 2017. VS 2015 did not report any problems. The warning disappeared after adding a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization (4.0.0) to each of the projects with the warning.

Comment: And don't forget to include it in your Unit Tests project! (That had me stumped for a while!)

Comment: This worked great unless adding the assembly returns the "A reference to 'mscorlib' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system." error.

In this case, I needed to open the .vbprol (.csproj) file and add a reference manually via:

    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `update-package -reinstall` command in the Package Manager Console.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem.